# Is the word "you" a pronoun in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, parts-of-speech

I am reading the book *High School English Grammar & Composition* by Wren & Martin.

While defining *Pronoun*, the following sentence appears as an example:

> The books are where you left them.

Now my question is, is the word "you" too a pronoun in this particular sentence, just like the word "them"?

The authors have italicised the latter word but not the former, which has been done because the former word does not replace any explicit noun in the sentence.

Here is Wren & Martin's definition of Pronoun:

> A *Pronoun* is a word used instead of a noun; ...

Answer (score 2):

"You" is always a pronoun.  The sentence might have been

> The books are where Saaqib left them.

And "Saaqib" is [definitely a noun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk4N5kkifGQ).

(It occurs to me that in the sentence "'You' is always a pronoun", "'you'" is an ordinary noun, [it's a word.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction))

Comment: It occurs to me that if addressed to a man, ***You** don't get pregnant just by kissing* is one of those relatively unusual contexts where ***you*** doesn't even *include* the addressee, let alone refer *specifically* to him.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — Wiktionary calls it an "*indefinite personal pronoun*" (meaning "anyone, one; an unspecified individual or group of individuals") but still a pronoun.